# Getting GitHub Branch protection returns "404 Not Found"

Tags: api, rest, github, curl, postman

I have tried to get the Branch policies using curl / Postman however I keep getting Error "404 Not Found".
[image]

Based on the documentation (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-branch-protection), I seem to be using the correct API Uri. see below commands used. Ps: Auth Token has been verified.

For Curl :

```
curl \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/branches/{branch}/protection
```

Postman:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/branches/{branch}/protection
```

I need API call to return the Branch protection. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

while at the moment not clearly documented,
this API URI requires the provided access token to have admin privileges for the repository.